# Destructuring declaration bug with the value

Tags: javascript, function, destruction

I can not understand why after destructuring assignment, `items` prop does not equal `Gorilla`.

It will be used after deleting the main prop `items: "Piggi"` in the origin object options. I do not understand why...

```js
    'use strict';
    
    let options = {
      size: 100,
      items: "Piggi"
    }
    
    let { title="Menu", items:w="Gorilla", size } = options;
    
    let a = title;
    let b = w;
    console.log(a + " - " + b);  // must be "Menu - Gorilla"
```

Comment: Where is the destruction you're talking about? All I can see is reassignement

Comment: @eithed - `let { title="Menu", items:w="Gorilla", size } = options;` Maybe you call it reassignment...

Comment: Code is working as expected, `Gorilla` will be the default value when `items` property is missing in the `options`.

Comment: Ah - destructuring != destruction

Comment: @HassanImam Ok, so how we can how can we force the code to take a value from the destructuring assigm., rather than from the object? Or it's impossible?

Comment: If you don't need value from the object then declare that variable separately or provide unique name to that variable, then you can provide default value to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the destructuring declaration with initialization here:

```
let { items:w = "Gorilla" } = options;
```

the syntax means to declare a variable called "w", whose value should be initialized to the value of the property called "items" in the object referenced by "options", or if there is no such property then to the string "Gorilla".

In your case, then, the variable "w" is initialized to the value of the "items" property in the original object.

If you don't want to take the value from the source object, then don't:

```
let w = "Gorilla";
```

Comment: So, as I understand, in the destructuring declaration we can not overwrite the value that previously assigned to the variable in the object

Comment: Right; the whole point of destructuring is to extract property values from inside a "source" object. If you don't want the property values, it doesn't make sense to use destructuring declaration. Note that you can combine a plain declaration/initialization with a destructuring declaration in the same `let` or `var` statement.

Answer (score 2):

When you analyze the code, you get three techniques working here:

1. [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

   ```
   { foo, bar }
   ```

   for

   ```
   { foo: foo, bar: bar}
   ```
2. [default values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values)

   ```
   { foo = 42 }
   ```

   which is

   ```
   { foo: foo = 42 }
   ```
3. change of the target in the [Object Property Assignment Pattern [You Don't Know JS: ES6 & Beyond, Chapter 2: Syntax]](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#object-property-assignment-pattern):

   > The syntactic pattern here is `source: target` (or `value: variable-alias`).

   ```
   { foo: bar }
   ```

The synthesis is a new target `w` for the old property `items` with a default value of `'Gorilla'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
let options = {
  size: 100,
  items: "Piggi"
}

let { title="Menu", items:w="Gorilla", size } = options;

let a = title;
let b = w;
console.log(a + " - " + b);
```

**Solution**- The problem is , we are overwriting the global object. it is why you have titile as Menu but option object does not have titile property. So, when you assign global object with option,
it still has items as "piggi"
plus you cannot assign object like this, you have to reassign each property in javascript.
*i hope you got your answer.*