# Distance - Cooldown formula

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, math

I am trying to code a program and what i want is to store 1. Distance and 2. Cooldown Time in my db. I get the input from the user's input string which is in `?dist 1.8254,25.212398 2.34235,25.232412`.

I have a nodejs application, that calculates the distance and prints the output as `The distance is 57.53 Km`. But I also want to display the cooldown time which in this case would be `60km - < 22 minutes`, so my program output would be `The distance is 57.53Km and the cooldown time is 20 minutes`. I said 20 minutes because it is <22 minutes for 60km, so difference of 1 minute acceptable.

I can use simple if/else to match this below conditions, but I want to store all the distance values (1-1500) in db along with its cooldown time. How do i generate/calculate the cooldown time? What formula may I use as per the given scenario?

I would be using sqlite as db.

I thought for a while,but i cant seem to find a solution.Also If i have missed tagging appropriate tags for my post, then pls re tag it.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

[image: Distance Cooldown]

Comment: do you have the list in text format? and please add what you have tried.

Comment: It would be better to post [mcve] version of your code rather than describing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take an array of objects for the wanted relation between distance and cooldown time. The struture take nomalized data with same units, like *km* for distances and *m* (minutes) for time.

> ```
> [
>     {
>         distance: 1,
>         cooldown: 1
>     },
>     {
>         distance: 3,
>         cooldown: 2
>     }, 
>     // ...
>     {
>         distance: 1500,
>         cooldown: 120
>     }
> ]
> ```

For finding an element of the array with data, [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) retuns the first element, if the condition is `true` or any other [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value. To prevent an exception an object is taken as default value, it it the part with [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()). The object is necessary, because of the following access of `cooldown` property.

```
cooldown = (data.find(({ distance: d }) => distance <= d) || {}).cooldown;
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                  find object
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                     destructuring
//                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                   condition
//                                                           ^^            default value
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^           check result
//                                                               ^^^^^^^^  final value
```

It uses `{ distance: d }` a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with a new name `d`, because the property name is already used as function parameter.

```js
function getCooldownTime(distance) {
    const
        data = [{ distance: 1, cooldown: 1 }, { distance: 3, cooldown: 2 }, { distance: 7, cooldown: 5 }, { distance: 10, cooldown: 7 }, { distance: 12, cooldown: 8 }, { distance: 18, cooldown: 10 }, { distance: 30, cooldown: 15 }, { distance: 65, cooldown: 22 }, { distance: 81, cooldown: 25 }, { distance: 250, cooldown: 45 }, { distance: 500, cooldown: 60 }, { distance: 700, cooldown: 85 }, { distance: 1000, cooldown: 90 }, { distance: 1500, cooldown: 120 }],
        cooldown = (data.find(o => distance <= o.distance) || {}).cooldown;

    return cooldown >= 60 ? (cooldown / 60) + ' hr' : cooldown + ' min';
}

console.log(getCooldownTime(0));
console.log(getCooldownTime(1));
console.log(getCooldownTime(2));
console.log(getCooldownTime(10));
console.log(getCooldownTime(100));
console.log(getCooldownTime(1000));
```

Comment: Please explain me this line `cooldown = (data.find(({ distance: d }) => distance <= d) || {}).cooldown;`. what is this syntax of `data` variable. Sorry I dont code much javascript so I am unaware about shorthand notations or in deep

Comment: data is just an array with objects. the yellow framed grey part.

Comment: yes understood...but I am confused with the `({distance:d})`, distance is the function argument and what is d? is distance renamed to d?

Comment: right, it is renamed to `d`, because `getCooldownTime` has a parameter with name `distance`. maybe you have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48138416/destructuring-declaration-bug-with-the-value/48138480#48138480) to point 3.

Comment: Thanks, and if I am correct, if you input distance as 10, so it will evaluate like 10.${cooldownvalue}, in this case it'll be 7, this is how it access the object's cooldown property?

Comment: with `10`, you get `'7 min'`. what is `10.${cooldownvalue},`?

Comment: `({ distance: d }) => distance <= d` is syntactic sugar for `function(thing) { var d = thing.distance; return (distance <= d); }`.

Answer (score 0):

I put your data into Excel and created an xy-scatter plot.  I tried a few different trend lines, but I thought that the power law fit best.  The agreement is better close up; the cooling is predicted to be longer at larger distances (e.g. predicts 134 min cooling time at 1500 km, 14 minutes longer than your 120 minute data).

```
cooling time (min) = 1.3962*(distance km)^0.6247
```

It's simple, easy to visualize, and works for all those distances in between the data values.  A continuous function is best.

The JavaScript function is easy to write:

```
function getCooldownTimeMinutes(distanceKm) {
    return 1.3962*Math.pow(distance, 0.6247);
}
```

I'll leave it to you to add all the other checks that make sense:

1. distance can't be null
2. distance is a number
3. distance is a positive definite number; no negatives.

You can improve on this a bit if you wish.  Up until 250 km the power law works fine.  Beyond that looks linear to me.  You can make this as elaborate as you wish.

How confident are you about your data?

By all means keep taking in data from users and storing it in your database.  You can periodically re-fit the data using least squares regression and the function of your choice.

[image]